# ¿cómo acceder a un método de una clase DERIVADA a través de un puntero de una clase BASE?

Tags: c++, punteros, herencia, clase-abstracta

tengo este código que se ha vuelto un pequeño *laberinto.*
Tengo un array dinámico hecho de una clase BASE llamada **LugarLaberinto**
y tengo dos clases DERIVADAS que son **muro** y **EspacioAbierto**

Básicamente lo que quiero es leer un archivo de texto con un laberinto que puede tener dimensiones variables y leer carácter por carácter el archivo y recrear el laberinto dentro de un array de punteros

```
LugarLaberinto*** lugares;
```

pero la clase derivada **EspacioAbierto** tiene métodos que me permiten cambiar el espacio Abierto con por ejemplo la persona dentro del laberinto.

mi pregunta entonces es ¿cómo acceder a un método de la clase **EspacioAbierto** a través de un puntero de una clase **LugarLaberinto**?

y aqui les dejo el codigo con los comentarios. (trate de hacer el código lo mas reducido para mostrar la duda, pero no pude reducirlo mas que esto. Gracias)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

//####################################
//clase BASE lugar del laberinto 
class LugarLaberinto
{
    public:
        virtual char mostrarCaracter()=0;
    protected:
        char caracter;
};


//####################################
//clase muro DERIVADA de lugar del laberinto 
class muro : public LugarLaberinto
{
    public: 
        muro();
        ~muro();
        char mostrarCaracter();
};

muro::muro()
{
    caracter = '#';
}

char muro::mostrarCaracter()
{
    return caracter;
}
//####################################
//clase espacioAbierto DERIVADA de lugar del laberinto 
class EspacioAbierto : public LugarLaberinto
{
    public:
        EspacioAbierto();
        ~EspacioAbierto();
        char mostrarCaracter();
        // funcion de la clase derivada
        void hayAlguien(bool);
};

EspacioAbierto::EspacioAbierto()
{
    caracter=' ';
}

char EspacioAbierto::mostrarCaracter()
{
    return caracter;
}

void EspacioAbierto::hayAlguien(bool)
{
    caracter='@';
}
//####################################
//clase laberinto
class laberinto
{
    public:
        //constructor que toma de un stream los valores del laberinto
        laberinto (std::ifstream&, int, int);
        ~laberinto();
        LugarLaberinto*** lugares;
        LugarLaberinto* obtenerLugar(int, int);
};

laberinto::laberinto(ifstream& fin, int alto, int ancho)
{
    char bloque;
    string auxiliar;

    lugares = new LugarLaberinto**[alto];
    //fin.ignore();
    for (int i=0; i< alto ; i++)
    {
        lugares[i] = new LugarLaberinto*[ancho];
        // leo una linea completa del archivo laberinto
        // y la guardo en auxiliar
        getline(fin,auxiliar);
        //cout << auxiliar;
        for (int j=0; j< ancho; j++)
        {
            //leo cada uno de los caracteres y los almaceno en la variable bloque
            bloque = auxiliar [j];
            // Basado en si es un # o si es un espacio basio creo el puntero 
            //hacia lugar de laberinto
            if (bloque=='#')
                this->lugares[i][j] = new muro();
            else 
            {
                this->lugares[i][j] = new EspacioAbierto();
                //########################
                //aqui esta mi duda
                // me gustaría acceder al metodo 
                // void hayAlguien(bool) 
                // a traves del puntero lugares
                // sin embargo no se si sea posible
                // o no se como hacerlo
                /*
                // aqui dice que la clase lugar laberinto no tiene
                //un miembro llamado hayAlguien y bueno eso lo sé
                // pero no quiero crear una funcion virtual para cada miembro
                // de esta clase derivada
                if (bloque=='@')
                    this->lugares[i][j]->hayAlguien(true);
                */
                // encontré esta manera de hacerlo pero no se si es la única
                // que es creando un nuevo objeto modificandolo y luego 
                // asignándolo, sin embargo no me siento totalmente cómodo
                // pensando que tengo que crear objetos a cada instante que 
                // quiera modificar el objeto.
                if (bloque=='@')
                {
                    EspacioAbierto *aux= new EspacioAbierto();
                    aux->hayAlguien(true);
                    lugares[i][j]=aux;

                }


            }

                //########################
            cout << this->lugares[i][j]->mostrarCaracter();
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

ifstream fin;
fin.open("laberinto.txt");
int alto = 10;
int ancho =10;
laberinto *nivel  =  new laberinto(fin, alto, ancho);
return 0;
}
```

para finalizar adjunto el archivo laberinto.txt

```
##########
#@#      #
# #####  #
#        #
######   #
#        #
#  #######
#   #    #
#       e#
##########
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tienes 4 formas:

### Aquí mando yo

Si estás **absolutamente seguro** de que tus punteros hacen referencia a las clases correctas, puedes utilizar un *forzado de tipos*. Usando estos 2 métodos, **es tu responsabilidad** el comprobar que un puntero a la clase base apunta **realmente** a una instancia de la clase hija.

Estas 2 formas **fuerzan** al compilador a aceptar *sin rechistar* lo que tu le indicas, por muy *ilógica* que sea la conversión.

1. Al modo C.

Utiliza la expresión `(clase_derivada *)puntero_a_clase_hija`:

```
LugarLaberinto *ll;

(muro *)ll->mostrarCaracter( );
```

Esta sintaxis es *heredada* de C. **No** deberías usarla, puesto que resulta complicado buscarla entre las líneas de código si, por algún motivo, has de realizar algún cambio.

2. Al modo C++.

Es similar al anterior, pero utilizamos la palabra reservada `reinterpret_cast`.

```
LugarLaberinto *ll;

reinterpret_cast< muro * >( ll )->mostrarCaracter( );
```

Esta sintaxis es mucho mas fácil de localizar; basta con realizar una búsqueda de `reinterpret_cast` en el texto, para encontrarla. Facilita cambios posteriores, y usa una sintaxis mas *al estilo C++*.

### Soy bueno, pero por si acaso

3. Utilizando `static_cast< >( )`.

Esto puede considerarse un método *mas suave* que los anteriores. **No** fuerza al compilador a admitir cualquier cosa; nos mostrará un error si los tipos implicados son claramente incompatibles.

```
LugaLaberinto *ll;

static_cast< muro * >( ll )->mostrarCaracter( );
```

### C++ ¡ Ayudame !

Ya que estás en C++, puedes aprovecharte de ello y dejar que sea el *runtime* del lenguaje el que comprueba que una instancia pertenece a una clases heredera de otra.

Para aprovecharte de esto, las clases **han de tener métodos virtuales**, cosa que ya tienes hecha en `LugarLaberinto`.

4. Utilizando `dynamic_cast< >( )`.

Similar a los anteriores:

```
LugaLaberinto *ll;
muro *m = dynamic_cast< muro * >( ll );

if( m ) {
  m->mostrarCaracter( );
  ...
```

Como ves, hacemos un uso *algo diferente*. El operador `dynamic_cast` devuelve **un puntero** si la conversión es posible, o `NULL` si la conversión **no** es posible (por ejemplo, porque el puntero original *apunta* a una clase no hija).

También, si lo utilizamos con *referencias*, en lugar de devolver `NULL` (cosa no posible con referencias), lanzará la excepción `std::bad_cast` si la conversión no es posible.

De las 4 formas posibles, `dynamic_cast` **es la única con coste** en tiempo de ejecución; todas las demás son realizadas *en tiempo de compilación*; está última sufre una mínima penalización, puesto que se realiza un comprobación sobre si los punteros a las clases son o no realmente compatibles (usando `la VTABLE; de ahí la necesidad de métodos virtuales).

Comment: @AngelAngel cierto, gracias :-) Corregido.

Comment: nada por cierto buena respuesta, elegante y simpatica Aqui mando yo. borrare este comentario. Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias por la rapida respuesta, se entiende todo perfectamente, solo que en honor a la correcta integración con mi codigo debo añadir que el método `mostrarCaracter()` pertenece a las tres clases, y no haría falta ponerle la casta, en vez de eso tendria que haber sido `static_cast<EspacioAbierto *>(lugares[i][j])->hayAlguien(true);`pero solo en honor a la integridad de mi codigo, ;)

Answer (score 2):

La respuesta de @Trauma me parece correcta, pero en general ese mecanismo de if/downcast puede reemplazarse usando una función virtual. Por ejemplo, tu clase base podría quedar:

```
class LugarLaberinto {
public:
    virtual char mostrarCaracter() = 0;
    virtual void hayAlguien(bool) { 
        /* aquí hacer lo que convenga cuando se intente amurar a alguien */  
    }
protected:
    char caracter;
};
```

A este mecanismo se lo suele llamar "Service request", que el usuario puede invocar para solicitar a un objeto la ejecución de una acción, si es que está disponible. Puedes encontrar los detalles en

> C++ FAQs, Second Edition  By Marshall Cline, Greg Lomow, Mike Girou

Comment: Si, correcto, eso funciona perfecto, solamente que la clase `lugarLaberinto` es **base** de otras dos clases, y la clase **derivada** `muro` no tiene el metodo `hayAlguien` ni muchos otros métodos que pienso adherir a la clase **derivada**  `espacioAbierto`, entonces tendria que _sobrecargar(?)_ de funciones virtuales la clase lugarLaberinto? cuando llame a la funcion `hayAlguien` con la clase **derivada** `muro` presiento que va a haber un error.. ¿hayAlguien dentro del muro?

Comment: @JacoboCórdova Como accedes a cada objeto por medio de un puntero polimórfico, cuando invoques el método `hayAlguien()`, si el tipo dinámico del puntero no tiene definido ese método, se invocará el de la clase base, que viene a ser el `hayAlguien()` por defecto de la familia. Considera que si sabes de antemano que vas a necesitar varias veces el mecanismo de `downcast` muy probablemente te convenga revisar ese diseño.

Comment: Comprendo.. es a lo que te referías con _amurar a alguien_, porque no haces el método "virtual puro" sino solamente virtual. Lo tendré en cuenta. muchas gracias

Comment: El problema que le vería a esta solución es que complica las clases. Si `hayAlguien` solo tiene sentido en una de las clases hija tu solución obliga a arrastrar la funcionalidad a toda la herencia.

Answer (score 2):

Venga, una alternativa más... patrón visitor:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Visitor;

struct A
{
  virtual void visit(Visitor& visitor) const;

  void funcA() const
  { std::cout << "funcA()\n"; }
};

struct B : A
{
  void visit(Visitor& visitor) const;

  void funcB() const
  { std::cout << "funcB()\n"; }
};

struct C : A
{
  void visit(Visitor& visitor) const;

  void funcC() const
  { std::cout << "funcC()\n"; }
};

struct Visitor
{
  void VisitA(const A& a)
  {
    a.funcA();
  }

  void VisitB(const B& b)
  {
    b.funcB();
  }

  void VisitC(const C& c)
  {
    c.funcC();
  }
};

void A::visit(Visitor& visitor) const
{ visitor.VisitA(*this); }

void B::visit(Visitor& visitor) const
{ visitor.VisitB(*this); }

void C::visit(Visitor& visitor) const
{ visitor.VisitC(*this); }

int main()
{
  std::vector<A*> lista { new A, new B, new C };

  Visitor visitor;
  for( size_t i=0; i<lista.size(); i++ )
    lista[i]->visit(visitor);

  // Faltan los deletes... lo se y no los he puesto porque
  // el tema no trata de eso
}
```

Una de las principales ventajas es que no hace falta realizar conversiones de ningún tipo ya que salvo que hagas cosas raras siempre vas a trabajar con tipos válidos.

La lógica de este patrón al principio choca un poco pero la verdad es que es bastante sencilla:

- Cada objeto de la jerarquía implementa su propia versión de `visit()`. Esta función es virtual y aquí es donde se empieza a obrar la magia.
- Cuando llamas a `lista[i]->visit()` se llamará al método `visit()` correspondiente al tipo actual (`A`, `B` o `C`). Cada una de las implementaciones interactúa con el objeto `Visitor` por una vía diferente (`VisitA`, `VisitB` o `VisitC`).
- Cada función `VisitX` de `Visitor` sabe trabajar con un tipo de objeto concreto, por lo que tiene acceso a toda su interfaz pública.

Este patrón puede ser bastante potente si se implementa con interfaces o, en el caso de C++, con clases abstractas. De esta forma puedes tener una clase base `Visitor` que básicamente sea tonta y después toda una colección de visitantes específicos para hacer tareas diversas:

- Uno para guardar los objetos en ficheros
- Uno para imprimir valores en pantalla
- Uno para filtrar elementos
- ...

Las posibilidades de programación son infinitas y lo bueno es que la lógica de visitación únicamente hay que programarla una vez.

Comment: Esto esta un poco loco de verdad.. tuve que releerlo un par de veces, y debo decir que estoy un poco maravillado de que posibilidades como estas existan. .. para lo que estoy haciendo en este momento me parece un poco excesivo pero agradezco mucho este conocimiento